# Setting value of input with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having problem trying to set the value for an input using jquery, basically you click on a link, and it takes you to a different page with a form, and I'm trying to set the value of one of the inputs of that form. I don't know why is not working. Here's my code:

page 1 (where you click the link that performs the function to set the value of the input)

```
<table class="tablaObjeto">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
          <img src="img/ps4Mall.jpg">
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="precio">
          <p>$<span id="precioPS4">400</span> - PS4</p>
        </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="botonCompra">
          <a id="botonCompraPS4" href="paginaSolicitudes.html"><img src="img/BotonCompra.png"></a>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

page 2 (form with the input that needs to show the value)

```
<tr>
  <td class="info">Precio: </td>
  <td class="inputs"><input id="precioI" name="precio" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

Here's the javascript (javascript/metodos.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#botonCompraPS4").click(function() {
        obtienePrecioPS4();
        $("#precioI").val(retornaPrecio());
    });
});

function obtienePrecioPS4() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("precio", $("#precioPS4").text());
}

function retornaPrecio() {
    var r = sessionStorage.getItem("precio");
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try loading the value on document ready, see below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#botonCompraPS4").click(function() {
        obtienePrecioPS4();
    });

    // Load value on document ready
    $("#precioI").val(retornaPrecio());
});
```

Your page1 and page2 should have the same javascript code above